# ORM for CodeIgniter 2.0

Tags: codeigniter, orm

What are some recommended ORM's for CodeIgniter? I have heard of Data Mapper and Propel. What are some that people have used and would recommend?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CI comes bundled with an [Active Record class](http://www.codeignitor.com/user_guide/database/active_record.html) -- which is confusing because the Active Record pattern is technically an ORM, however the class is not -- it is merely a query builder.  With that said, for basic websites I'd highly suggest using it.

Which ORM to actually use with CI is more a matter of personal preference though, [DataMapper](http://stensi.com/datamapper/) is more of a basic ORM and was actually written specifically for CI, but it won't give you all of the functionality found in something like [Doctrine](http://www.doctrine-project.org/) which I tend to think is one of the most full featured ORM's for PHP.

Overall you'll likely want to try out a few and find out which one suits your needs the best, there is a lot of information about ORM's for PHP on the [PHP Info page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/php/info) right here on StackOverflow.